# Entity Framework в трехслойной архитектуре

Tags: .net

использую подход database-first, в какой слой добавлять модель edmx?

Comment: добавляйте в DAL (Data Access Layer)

Comment: как тогда прокинуть сущности из DAL в PL?

Comment: ну по хорошему в BLL (Business Logic Layer) получаем из DAL `Entity`,  конвертируем в `EntityDto` и передаем в PL. (для справки [Dto](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/data-transfer-object.html))

Comment: Если я хочу реализовать паттерн mvc в PL,то тогда получается EntityDTO нужно передавать на view без добавления viewmodel и конвертации EntityDTO в view models?